# changing the class when clicked in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I have a list of `li` tags and by default the first `li` tag is active by default. Now on click of any of the other `li` tag I am calling a function called `displayData`. Also I need to make the clicked `li` active and remove active class on other `li` elements. How to do this in AngularJs?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href>Karnataka<span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">{{totalCount}}</span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sub-headers">
        <li class="sub-header active" ng-click="displayData('bangalore')"><a href>Bangalore<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{bCount}}</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('hubli')"><a href>Bangalore<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{hCount}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href>Kerala<span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">{{keralaCount}}</span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sub-headers">
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('cochin')"><a href>Cochin<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{cochinCount}}</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('tvn')"><a href>Trivendrum<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{tvnCount}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href>Gujarat<span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">{{gujCount}}</span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sub-headers">
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('baroda')"><a href>Baroda<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{barodaCount}}</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('ahemedabad')"><a href>Ahemadabad<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{ahmdCount}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TamilNadu<span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">{{tamilnaduCount}}</span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sub-headers">
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('chennai')"><a href>Chennai<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{chennaiCount}}</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-header" ng-click="displayData('madurai')"><a href>Ahemadabad<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">{{maduraiCount}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Read the documentation for ng-class. Please make a minimal code example dumping a wall of code does no good. Show us how you attempted to solve

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Read ngClass [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Now the solution, example code how to achieve it -

**HTML :**

```
  <li ng-class="bangaloreclass" ng-click="displayData('bangalore')" ..../>
  <li ng-class="hubliclass" ng-click="displayData('hubli')" ......./>
```

**Controller :**

```
  $scope.bangaloreclass = 'active'; //by default bangalore data selected
  $scope.hubliclass = ''; // by default hubli data not selected

  $scope.displayData = function(city) {
      if (city == 'bangalore') {
          $scope.bangaloreclass = 'active';
          $scope.hubliclass = '';
      } else if (city == 'hubli') {
          $scope.bangaloreclass = '';
          $scope.hubliclass = 'active';
      }
  }
```

Apply this logic to all `li` elements, I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, Add *ng-class*(with condition as shown below) and function in *ng-click* to the list items when you are in need of. This way,

```
ng-class="{active: ($index == selected)}"
```

ng-click function call as (pass the parameter- providing distinctness of clicked item),

```
ng-click="showActive($index)"
```

and in JS write  the function as (I intended writing the function below, within controller function),

```
$scope.showActive = function(index){$scope.selected = index;}
```

You can change the active class by resetting the *selected*, can be done by

```
 i.e. $scope.selected = -1
```